# TypeScript: How to initialize object with dynamic keys using index signature?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to simplify the following so that when I have a new product type, I do not need to add another line of code for the new product type to initialize it? There is syntax error if I do not initialize the variable.

```
enum ProductType {
   PC = 'pc',
   LAPTOP = 'laptop',
   TV = 'tv'
}

let productList: { [key in ProductType]: Product[] | undefined } = {
  [ProductType.PC]: undefined,
  [ProductType.LAPTOP]: undefined,
  [ProductType.TV]: undefined
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how `ProductType` is implemented?

Comment: Why have you added the typescript2.0 tag? Are you using TypeScript v2?

Comment: Area all of these properties actually *required*? Don't you just want `let productList: { [key in ProductType]?: Product[] | undefined } = { }` or even easier `let productList: Record<ProductType, Product[] | undefined> = { }`

Comment: @Garuno Added. Forgot to add it, my bad.

Comment: @caTS I have removed the tag. I'm new in TypeScript.

Comment: There's no index signature in this question; what you have is a mapped type, and you can therefore make the keys optional with an optional modifier as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/W4nY1N).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining (unless VLAZ wants to, given that mostly they already said this); if not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply.)

Comment: @jcalz I used the answer given by VLAZ. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded it as suggested by VLAZ

```
let productList: { [key in ProductType]?: UserProduct[] | undefined } = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If only I have understood you correctly, you want to avoid adding new line with every new `ProductType` for the initialization object, here is one of the possible solutions. Making it more dynamic with reducing over the enum's keys into an object.

```
enum ProductType {
  PC = 'pc',
  Laptop = 'laptop',
}

const o = Object.values(ProductType).reduce(
   (acc, key) => ({
      ...acc,
      [key]: undefined,
   }),
   {} as Record<ProductType, undefined>
);

// const o = { pc: undefined, laptop: undefined };
```

Comment: Thank you. I coded it as suggested by VLAZ